How to show the background color of a text in Terminal.app?
On VSCode it's like this:

On Terminal.app it's like this:

Any way to fix it?
The starship preset is from here by the way: https://starship.rs/presets/tokyo-night#tokyo-night-preset

It looks to me the theme uses true colors which is not supported by Terminal.app. Try a theme that uses only the 256-color palette, or switch to another terminal emulator such as iTerm2 (you may also need to disable its "minimum contrast" feature).

Thanks! @egmont. I'll be using iTerm2 instead yeah. I heard about Kitty and Alacritty too. I don't know the differences tho.
